# Javascript event handler fires "error: CS1026: ) expected" exception

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, controls, dom-events

I've created a table of dynamic controls which each row is a couple of (DropDownList and TextBox) then I've associated an event handler on each DropDownList selected change event so I can change on its TextBox as the code below shows :

```
DropDownList TypeDDL = new DropDownList();
    TypeDDL.ID = "TypeDDL_" + rowN.ToString();
    TypeDDL.Width = 120;
    TypeDDL.Height = 20;
    InitializeTypeDDL(TypeDDL);
    TypeDDL.AutoPostBack = true;
    TypeDDL.Attributes.Add("onchange", "javascript:handleFieldsDDLEvent(this);");
    TextBox FieldsDDL = new TextBox();
    FieldsDDL.ID = "FieldsDDL_" + rowN.ToString();
    FieldsDDL.Width = 120;
    FieldsDDL.Height = 20;
    FieldsDDL.Attributes.Add("style", "float:right");
```

but the Javascript code of the event handler fires an exceptions telling:

```
function handleFieldsDDLEvent(e) {
    var elementId = (e.target || e.srcElement).id;
    var IdArray = elementId.Split('_');
    var ControlId = "Control_"+IdArray[1].toString();

    if (IdArray[1] != "") {
        var FieldsDDL = document.getElementById("<%="+ControlId +".ClientID%>"); 
        // error CS1026: ) expected 

    ValueTxtBx.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us the _generated_ JavaScript please – the code the browser is actually receiving.

Comment: What is the value of `ControlId`?

Comment: You can't pass a client side variable (`ControlId`) into server side code, as server side code has already been processed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your javascript you have

```
var FieldsDDL = document.getElementById("<%="+ControlId +".ClientID%>");
```

The `<%= ... %>` parts are rendered on the server so it cannot be done this way in javascript.